# Requirement looks like a filename, but the file does not exist

Tags: python, opencv, pip

Хочу импортировать библиотеку `opencv2` на Питон 3.7, но при установке `numpy.whl` и `opencv.whl` выдаёт ошибку:

> ```
> C:\Users\User>pip install "numpy-1.14.5+mkl-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl"
> Requirement 'numpy-1.14.5+mkl-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl' looks like a filename, 
>     but the file does not exist
>
> numpy-1.14.5+mkl-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
> ```

У меня установлен `Python-3.7` и `opencv-3.4.1-vc14_vc15`,
я скачал `numpy-1.14.5+mkl-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` и
`opencv_python-3.4.2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Ошибка означает, что фала numpy-1.14.5+mkl-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl в каталоге C:\Users\User нет.

Comment: у вас Python 64-битный?

Comment: да  у меня 64-битный что мне делат я не смог найти решение

Comment: Откатитесь до пайтона 3.6,  много модулей стало выдавать ошибки после выхода новой версии, дайте время разрабам обновить их